# Can C language call the DLL written in c++ if not c++ compiler available?

Tags: c++, c, dll

I have a DLL to control some external device written in C++. But in the development I use ANSI C (not c++ supported) so I can only compile the code in pure C syntax.

I wonder if it is possible to load the DLL written in C++ in my C code, is DLL language dependent? Is there something called C++ DLL or C DLL or C# DLL?

If so, does it mean we can only call the DLL in the code in the same language? I did a search online and I found something about call C in C++ environment, they suggest to use `extern C {}` statement. But I think my case is just the opposite, I need to call C++ in C, but how can I do that while my compiler doesn't support C++?

Comment: Someone will probably have a better answer, but as far as I know, you'd need to use the `extern c {}` construct in the C++ code so that the function names don't get mangled.  Otherwise, the C++ entry points will be almost unreadable.  There may also be differences in calling convention depending on the compiler/platform.  I'm sure someone else will address those issues.

Comment: @Eric: That sounds like a good answer to me... How about you make it an answer?

Comment: If you need any C++ runtime support at all, you're going to be in bad shape.  Why can't you use a C++ compiler?

Comment: what compiler are you using?  It's really hard to be on a windows platform and have JUST a C compiler.

Comment: Ask whoever gave you the DLL what the proper way to use the DLL is.

Comment: I am using labview CVI which is a pure C compiler though it also support MSVC and could be compiled in come c++ environment but since everything is running in the server and my IT won't install any other compiler for that :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder if it is possible to load the DLL written in C++ in my C code.

Yes, you can load a shared object (or dynamically linked library) using C code no matter what language was used to create it, as long as all run-time requirements are met.

> is DLL language dependent?

Shared object itself is a binary in some format (i.e. on Linux it is [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format)). It has nothing to do with a language it was created from. For example, you could in theory write a DLL in hex editor, so that there would be no «language» it was created from.

> Is that something call C++ DLL or C DLL or C# DLL?

Theoretically you could call some DLL as «C++ DLL» if you know that it was created by compiling C++ code, for example. Or maybe if it depends on C++-specific runtime libraries. However, from the system point of view, it is still an executable binary object and the system doesn't care what language and/or compiler (if any) was used to create it.

> … does it mean we can only call the DLL in the code in the same language?

No.

> I did a search online and I found something about call C in C++ environment.

You need to be aware of [Application Binary Interface (ABI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) that describes the low-level interface between a computer program and the operating system or another program. In case with C++, on top of everything else you also need to know how [symbol names are being mangled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling), what exception mechanism is being used. And that depends on a particular machine/operating system/compiler combination.

If you know that and your «C++ DLL» is loadable and executable (i.e. all run-time dependencies are there), you can pretty much host that DLL in a C program (even without that DLL providing C interface through «extern "C"» statements). For example, knowing the size of an object (i.e. class), its layout requirements, its mangled constructor/destructor function names (if any), you could allocate memory and construct that object. Then, if you know mangled names of methods and how «this» pointer is passed around, you can invoke them.

**Don't do it!**

That being said, this is by all means the last thing you need to be trying to do. It is a lot easier to just get a proper C++ compiler that matches ABI of that DLL, get header files describing the interface you want to use and use it like normal people do. It could even be easier to implement the functionality of that DLL yourself rather than trying to hack around. So, please try something else. As good samaritans have already suggested in comments — «Ask whoever gave you the DLL what the proper way to use the DLL is»

Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the implementation of the functions in the DLL.

If the functions are exposing C++ features, such as returning class objects, taking parameters of type `std::string` (or any other class object) or throwing exceptions, you are going to struggle to use that in a meaningful way from C.

However, if all the exported functions are using standard C interfaces (strings are pointer to `char`, no exceptions [1], no returning of class objects, etc), then yes. But bear in mind that nobody will want to use the DLL if it "leaks exceptions" for example.

[1] This really means that unless it's 100% sure that a call won't throw an exception - see later for details - then you have to use `try { code goes here } catch(...) { catch-all code here }` in every function.

It is very hard to avoid exceptions in modern C++ - an innocent statement such as `vector<int> v; ... v.push_back(42); ...` could cause a `bad_alloc` exception, for example.

In summary, it's quite complicated to get everything right - if you actually want to write a C++ DLL, then you want to use it from C++. If you want a C-callable DLL, then write it in C, as a general rule.

Answer (score 1):

A DLL is not technically language-dependent in the sense that it is an executable format and potentially any language could be compiled to machine code that calls into the DLL, but in normal practice they are language-dependent due to the fact that a DLL doesn't generally contain enough information for another executable to call its functions.  The missing information is primarily the calling convention, which determines how machine registers and the stack is operated by the caller (your program) and the callee (the DLL).  And as far as I understand, these things are only loosely standardized and not always compatible between compilers.  However, there are certain conventions you can follow to ensure that a DLL is "mostly" inter-operable between compilers.

With regard to C code calling C++ specifically, whether or not it will work (easily) depends on the type of functions exported by the DLL.  If they are non-static member functions of some class, you are probably going to be in for a rough ride.  But if they are "regular" static functions and only use C-compatible types as arguments and return values, it may even be straight-forward (although still not guaranteed, I think).  This information ought to be found in a header file that would have come along with the DLL.  You'll also need to know the "mangled" names of the functions, which can be determined using a tool like dumpbin (available if you have a Visual Studio tool chain installed).

Answer (score 0):

If the DLLL uses C++ features, then your best bet is to make a wrapper DLL using a C++ compiler outside of the CVI enviroment.  This DLL can create a C callable interface to the C++ DLL, then you can integrate this DLL into the CVI enviroment.